# What is the difference between the two conversion methods?

Tags: c++, type-conversion, hex

I have the following code (to convert from a float number to a hex number):

```
float decimal = 12.1;
int num = (int) decimal;        // <- (Method 1)
int num2 = (*(int*) &decimal); //  <- (Method 2)

cout << hex << num << "\n";
cout << hex << num2 << "\n";
```

**The result:**
0xc
0x4141999a

The second one outputs a correct floating number in hexadecimal.

**I have two questions:**

- What is the difference between the two ways?
- How does the conversion mechanism work in the second way?

Comment: T - > U and T* -> U* - the latter is not a float number conversion.

Comment: (2) is undefined behavior.

Comment: The second one says “pretend that the bits of the `float` in `decimal` are the bits of an `int`. Pretending doesn’t make it true.

Comment: @Pete Becker: But when using a [converter](https://gregstoll.com/~gregstoll/floattohex/) like that to convert a floating point number to hex I find my result is the same as the converter result so, what is the correct way for conversion if the second way is wrong?

Comment: For 2nd see [What is the strict aliasing rule?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule)

Comment: To examine the bit pattern of a float, use `std::bit_cast` if you have c++20. Otherwise, use `memcpy`. Search for the term "type punning" and you'll get a lot of answers on SO.

Comment: I don't know who said it was a duplicate of `*(int*)number`, but that is definitely very much incorrect. This question clearly says `*(int*)&number`. Notice the extra `&`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Method 1

   ```
   int num = (int) decimal;
   ```

   In Method 1, you do a `floorf()` on a positive decimal number and a `ceilf()` on negative numbers. So the result is expected to be 12 in your case. (i.e. if `decimal` was set to 12.9, you would still get 12 in `num`.)
2. Method 2

   ```
    int num2 = (*(int*) &decimal);
   ```

   In Method 2, you get the 32 bits of the decimal number and print that as an integer. So you get what you could view as a *weird number*, it's just the [floating point number in hexadecimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format).

   [image]

   I very often use that to save such numbers to disk or put them in a message so that way they don't get converted.

   Note: you are also lucky that your `int` is 32 bits. It could have been 64 bits and the output would be different. To verify that you're using the correct size you can use:

   ```
   int num2;
   if(sizeof(num2) != sizeof(decimal))
   {
       throw std::range_error("error: cannot do that.");
   }
   num2 = (*(int*) &decimal);
   ```

   In order to have the correct size, you may want o consider using integers with a specific size: `std::uint32_t` for a `float` and `std::uint64_t` for a `double`. I show "uint" because it's more conventional to use unsigned integers in this case, although `int` works too since the sign is the same for integers and floating point in this case (bit 31 or bit 63 represent the sign), however, the mantissa of a floating point is always represented as a positive number. So I think that the `uint` is less confusing.

---

I do not think that there is a right way and a wrong way. Both of these are very useful in C/C++. In most cases, though, Method 1 is probably what you want/need, although you may need to use a function such as `roundf()`¹ or `floorf()`¹ to get the exact outcome you are looking for.

---

**Notes:**
¹ The functions that end with `f` are for `float`. For `double`, use the function without the `f` at the end. Check the man pages for additional details: `man roundf`.

Comment: So, If the second way is wrong, what is the correct conversion?

Comment: These days, `std::bitcast`. In the old days, `std::memcpy`. In the even older days you said, <expletive deleted> it and used an illegal cast because the compiler wasn't all that likely to (and to be honest, still isn't) to do anything crazy. Not for something this simple.

Comment: Converting `float` to `int` is not the same as `floor()`.   It always rounds toward zero which `floor()` doesn't do for negative values.

Comment: @LionKing I added some details to my answer.